# Reemplazar el valor de NULL por un valor fijo en un Join SQL Server

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2012

estoy uniendo dos tablas en SQL Mediante un LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT        V_InvoiceHeader.IDFactura, V_InvoiceHeader.FechaDocumento, V_InvoiceHeader.NombreCliente, V_InvoiceHeader.NIT, V_InvoiceHeader.DireccionFacturacion, V_InvoiceHeader.FOLIO, V_InvoiceHeader.Subfolio, 
                         V_InvoiceHeader.Habitacion, V_InvoiceHeader.SERIE, V_InvoiceHeader.NumeroDoc, V_InvoiceHeader.IDVendor, CASE IDClienteIQware WHEN 'CF' THEN '0' END AS IDClienteIQware, ClientesCXC.IDSap, 
                         V_InvoiceHeader.DocType
FROM            V_InvoiceHeader LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         ClientesCXC ON V_InvoiceHeader.NIT = ClientesCXC.NIT
```

Y este es un ejemplo de los resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos los valores NULL que tengo en la columna IDSAP es porque no encuentra coincidencia con la segunda tabla (ClientesCxC). Quisiera poder reemplazar ese valor para que en lugar de devolverme un valor null, me devuelva el valor 'CIQware'. Será esto posible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el [ISNULL()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp) para cambiar automaticamente el valor cuando detecte un nulo:

```
SELECT V_InvoiceHeader.IDFactura
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.FechaDocumento
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.NombreCliente
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.NIT
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.DireccionFacturacion
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.FOLIO
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.Subfolio
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.Habitacion
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.SERIE
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.NumeroDoc
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.IDVendor
    ,CASE IDClienteIQware
        WHEN 'CF'
            THEN '0'
        END AS IDClienteIQware
    ,ISNULL(ClientesCXC.IDSap,'CIQware')
    ,V_InvoiceHeader.DocType
FROM V_InvoiceHeader
LEFT JOIN ClientesCXC ON V_InvoiceHeader.NIT = ClientesCXC.NIT
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, marco tu respuesta como correcta, fue de mucha ayuda.

Comment: De nada amigo, me alegra haberte ayudado.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, desconocía esa función! :D

Answer (score 1):

Para ello sólo debes realizar un **[CASE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** de la siguiente forma:

```
CASE
   WHEN ClientesCXC.IDSap IS NULL THEN 'CIQware'
END
```

Con eso debería ser suficiente :)

Comment: +1 por que tu respuesta también es correcta